# ReactJs - how can I go back from displaying nested child component to displaying just first parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs

> SubmitForm  -parent->  Results  -parent-> Presentation 
>   -parent-> ButtonBackToSearch

I'm trying to learn how to proper think in ReactJs and create single page app.

I'm building Wikipedia Viewer in React. In my < SubmitForm /> component my users input data, then in < Results  /> component data is being prepared.
Next it is presented in < Presentation /> component. When < Presentation /> component is active I hide in css < SubmitForm /> with search window.

And < Presentation /> component  is parent for last component < ButtonBackToSearch />. This component has one button with this code:

```
import React from 'react';

export default class ButtonBackToSearch extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {isBackToggleOn: false};

    // This binding is necessary to make `this` work in the callback
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick() {
    this.setState({isBackToggleOn: true});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>
          BACK
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Now I have serious riddle. When user clicks BACK button and isBackToggleOn is true, how can I "destroy" all of this loaded components:  Results, Presentation, ButtonBackToSearch and go back to < SubmitForm /> to prepare for next search?

I could of course reload page, but reloading all page (F5) would be like cheating, right?

What is proper way of doing that in React?

[image]
[image]

This is my SubmitForm code:

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

import Title from './Title';
import Results from './Results';

export default class SubmitForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: null,
      value: '',
      display: ''
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  axiosStart() {
    const wikiApiUrl = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&format=json&origin=*&search=';
    const wikiApiUrlWithQuery = wikiApiUrl + this.state.value;
    axios.get(wikiApiUrlWithQuery) 
      .then(response => {
        console.log('@axiosStart was launched by user!');
        this.setState(Object.assign({}, this.state, { data: response.data }))
      }) 
      .catch(err => {
        console.log('Error: => ' + err);
        this.setState(Object.assign({}, this.state, { data: 'error' }))
      });
    this.setState({display: 'displayNone'});
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({value: event.target.value});
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    console.log(('An input was submitted: ' + this.state.value));
    // handle change has just updated state
    // now app can start axios with entered query
    // as soon as user submits
    this.axiosStart();
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className={this.state.display}>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <label>
            <Title />
            <input className="wiki_query" type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} autoFocus />
          </label>
          <button className="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="Submit">Search</button>
        </form>
        </div>
        <Results dataReady={this.state.data} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have three components

`MainScreen
Form
Results`

`MainScreen` would manage what screen to display to a user: Result, Form or Default.

`BackButton` would accept a callback to call when is clicked. Handler will be `MainScreen` itself and will change state of what screen to display.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this would be to make `ButtonBackToSearch` a child of `SubmitForm` itself. As you have described - it changes state of the Submit form itself and has no real connection to the `Presentation` or `Results` components. This would be in my view the cleanest "react" way to do this kind of interaction.

Although real life might be a bit more complicated than that and you might argue that button does have to be child of the nested components due to other unmentioned reasons. In this case your can take two approaches:

1. Use [context](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html). In the simplest case just put SubmitForm instance in context and expose method `goBack`. Then access submit form instance from call this method from button and call this method.
2. Make all components to have a mandatory property `parent`. This way you will always be able to navigate "up" the hierarchy tree and find whatever parent you need. After that do the same as in #1. It might sounds a bit overkill - but it might come in handy.

P.S.

3. Pass handler to "goBack" function defined in `SubmitForm` down through all components. This is a much uglier variation of #2 and **I do not recommend** you going this way as it will pretty fast pollute your components properties in more or less larger project.